# Search with different value in array each time

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

i need guide or help for how to search with different value 'airport' each time ‘values that define in array ‘ instead of type it hardcoded, 
thanks in advance  and i hope to find answer to use it in incoming scripts

`````
it('select the origin Airport', function () {
        for (let i in ['DXB dubai', 'AUH Abu Dhabi', 'JED Jeddah'])
        // select the oragain
        cy.get('[id="flights-search-origin-1"]')
            .type('DXB dubai', {force: true}).should('have.value’,’one of the array's values ')````
`````

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
it('select the origin Airport', () => {
  ['DXB dubai', 'AUH Abu Dhabi', 'JED Jeddah'].map(airport => {
    cy
      .get('[id="flights-search-origin-1"]')
      .clear().type(airport)
      .should('have.value', airport);
  })
})
```

Edit:
I've added a `.clear` before `.type`, and an assertion with the same value you've asked to type. Keep in mind this isn't an incredibly useful test, but it's what you've asked for.

Comment: thanks for your reply , how to let script take random *one* value from the array , as i see it take the 3 values together
i want one value in order to assert , thanks
`
it('select the origin Airport', function () {
        ['DXB dubai', 'AUH Abu Dhabi', 'JED Jeddah'].map(airport => {
          cy
          .get('[id="flights-search-origin-1"]')
          .type(airport, {force: true}).should('be.oneOf', airport)
`